# How to handle tinyxml null pointer returned on GetText()

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml, null-pointer

```
TiXmlElement *pElem;    
std::string StatusResponse;
pElem = hResponse.FirstChild("StatusResponse").Element();

if (pElem)
    StatusResponse = pElem->GetText();
```

If `pElem` is valid but the element contains no text, `pElem->GetText()` returns a NULL pointer, causing an exception. How should I handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (pElem && pElem->GetText())
    StatusResponse = pElem->GetText();
```

Comment: How painfully obvious. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would store the return value of GetText() to a local variable to avoid calling GetText() twice.